# How to update the nested array in json using oracle

Tags: arrays, json, oracle, parent-child

```sql
update sb_layout_defn
set    SB_LAYOUT_DEFN_DATA = json_transform (
                               SB_LAYOUT_DEFN_DATA, 
                               replace '$.filterDefaults.defaultValue' = 'FIRST'
                             )
where  json_exists(
         sb_layout_defn.SB_LAYOUT_DEFN_DATA,
         '$?(@.filterDefaults.defaultValue=="SECOND")'
       );
```

```json
"screenFilterDefaultDefn":[
  {
    "id":"art-group-id-1",
    "collectionId":"ADVENTURE_WORKS",
    "filterDefaults":[
      {
        "id":"ART-FILTER-DEF-0",
        "defaultValue":"SECOND"
      },
      {
        "id":"ART-FILTER-DEF-1",
        "defaultValue":"PENULT"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I need to update the default value in this..

Answer (score 0):

You can update the value of the first array element of `filterDefaults` using a `JSON_TRANSFORM` statement like this:

```sql
UPDATE sb_layout_defn SET SB_LAYOUT_DEFN_DATA = JSON_TRANSFORM(SB_LAYOUT_DEFN_DATA, SET '$.screenFilterDefaultDefn[0].filterDefaults[0].defaultValue' = 'FIRST' );
```